# Disable system("mkdir /a/b") call output

Tags: c++, linux, system

A simple question:
I'm using

```
system("mkdir /some/dest/");
```

on my program. How do I disable its output to the screen when running my program because if the dir exists, I get "mkdir: cannot create directory `/some/dest/': File exists"

Tried to run

```
system("mkdir /some/dest/ > /dev/null");
```

but it didn't work

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just call the `mkdir` function from your own program?

Comment: @hvd I do, the function is called from the code..If I got you right

Comment: No, you're calling the `system` function to execute the `mkdir` program, you're not calling the `mkdir` function.

Comment: is it a privilege problem? Do you have write access to the folder?

Comment: Oh ok, but won't it print the same if the dir already exists?

Comment: No, you are calling a shell command. you should just call a `mkdir` function directly without `system`

Comment: No, printing the error message is a property of the `mkdir` program. The `mkdir` function just returns whether it succeeds, and nothing gets printed unless you do so from your own code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a weird way to create directories from C code, taking into account that `mkdir (1)` itself is just a wrapper for `mkdir (2)` system call.

I'd recommend using `mkdir (2)`.

P.s. By `(2)` I mean `man` category of documentation (`$ man 2 mkdir`), this is a category for system calls.

Answer (score 4):

There are two streams, stdout and stderr. You are redirecting only strout, not stderr.

You need to redirect stderr to /dev/null as well; read your shell manual. In bash I think you can do:

```
mkdir /some/dest/ &> /dev/null
```

This answer your question about how to hide error messages when calling system(), but the  advice from other answers (using native C function mkdir) is more C/C++ idiomatic.

Comment: That, as far as I can tell, is perfectly valid POSIX sh with a different meaning: first, run `mkdir /some/dest/` in the background (`&`), then write nothing to `/dev/null`. I know at least that other shells interpret it as such.

Comment: @hwd: bash example taken from http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html.

Comment: I didn't comment because wouldn't work with bash, I commented because you really shouldn't assume bash when calling `system`. billz's answer uses `>/dev/null 2>&1`, which works just as well in bash and has the additional benefit of not breaking when (for example) dash is installed as `/bin/sh`.

Comment: I don't assume bash and specifically told the OP to read his shell manual. If you have a suggestion that will work across every shell out there it is welcome.